# Applying for an Uruguayan visa

Tags: visas, uruguay

I want to apply for an Uruguayan tourist visa. I have an Indian passport in Germany.

I have found and filled out the [form available at the website](http://conuruale.de/SOLICITUD%20DE%20VISA%20%28ale%29.pdf).

Due to the *over-simplified* website, I don't know how do I submit the form. Is there an appointment service that I should apply to first? It does not even state anywhere if I need to submit other documents.

Should I just go in the consulate and hand in my documents? Has someone else ever applied for an Uruguayan visa and could provide concise steps to get one?

Links: [**Website for Uruguayan Consulate in Germany**](http://conuruale.de/) (available only in Spanish and German)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is written on the website "`Um die benötigten Unterlagen für einen Visumantrag zu erfahren, setzen Sie sich bitte mit dem für Sie   zuständigen Konsulat in Verbindung` "  Simplified: Call the Consulate for time or further information. You have to fill the application form (download it from website)  in anycase and they can also ask for further documents (Which they can tell you only when you call or go there). http://conuruale.de/Kontakt.html